# How to prove: A negative number has an $n$-th root if $n$ is odd

Tags: continuity

**Statement:**

If $n$ is an odd positive integer and $a<0$. prove that there is exactly one negative $b$ such that $b^n = a$

**Proof**: let $n= 2k+1$ where $k \in \mathbb N$

let $c < 0$ s.t. $c<a<0$

And consider the function $f(x) =x^{2k+1} $ defined on $[c,0]$, the function is continuous on the interval $(c,0)$.

the two endpoint values will be
$ f(c)= c^{2k+1} <0 $
and $f(0) = 0$

here $c^{2k+1} <c<a<0$ implies  $f(c)=c^{2k+1}<a<0= f(0)$

thus by the intermediate value theorem we have $f(x)=a$ for some $x\in [c,0]$  say $x=b$.

This proves the existence of at least one negative b such that  $b^n = a$

there can't be more than one such $b$ because $f$ is strictly increasing on $(c,0)$.

This completes the proof.

---

I have proven this theorem in this way. Am i doing it right or it needs correction ? can anyone comment on this proof?

Comment: This is valid. It could be shortened provided you can use a similar result concerning uniqueness of positive $r$ for which $r^n=c$ in case $c>0.$ [However to prove that requires an argument not much different from the one you gave.]

Comment: For future reference, you can use `$\in$` to write the symbol "$\in$", instead of `$\epsilon$`. $a\in A$ looks much nicer than $a\epsilon A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your proof, you claim that $c^n < c$. But all you know is that $c<0$, and that is not enough to conclude $c^n < c$. For example, if $c=-\frac12$, and $n=3$, then

$$c^n = \left(-\frac12\right)^3 = -\frac18 > c.$$

---

Having said that, the main idea of your proof is correct. If you only improve the choice of $c$, you should be able to complete the proof!

Comment: If i choose c<-1. will that be correct?

Comment: @PrashantAnand exactly, you need to pick some $c$ such that $c<-1$. You can easily do this by simply taking $c=a-1$.